Calculating Exponential Moving Average (EMA) in Polars with ewm_mean or another method
Please note, this is related to Exponential Moving Average (EMA) calculations in Polars dataframe that I raised 7 months ago.
Suppose I have the following values:
values = [143.15,143.1,143.06,143.01,143.03,143.09,143.14,143.18,143.2,143.2,143.2,143.31,143.38,143.35,143.34,143.25,143.33,143.3,143.33,143.36]

Using Pandas and TA-Lib, I can perform the following:
import pandas as pd
import talib as ta

df_pan = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'value': values
    }
)

df_pan['ema_9'] = ta.EMA(df_pan['value'], timeperiod=9)

Resulting in:
    value   ema_9
0   143.15  NaN
1   143.10  NaN
2   143.06  NaN
3   143.01  NaN
4   143.03  NaN
5   143.09  NaN
6   143.14  NaN
7   143.18  NaN
8   143.20  143.106667
9   143.20  143.125333
10  143.20  143.140267
11  143.31  143.174213
12  143.38  143.215371
13  143.35  143.242297
14  143.34  143.261837
15  143.25  143.259470
16  143.33  143.273576
17  143.30  143.278861
18  143.33  143.289089
19  143.36  143.303271

In Polars, I had been doing the following:
import polars as pl

df_pol = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            'value': values
        }
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col('value').cum_count() < 9)
        .then(pl.col('value').head(9).mean())
        .otherwise(pl.col('value'))
        .ewm_mean(span=9, min_periods=9, ignore_nulls=True, adjust=False)
        .alias('ema_9')
    )
)

and I had been getting identical results to TA-Lib, but for reasons I am unable fathom, I now get the following:
value   ema_9
f64 f64
143.15  null
143.1   null
143.06  null
143.01  null
143.03  null
143.09  null
143.14  null
143.18  null
143.2   143.125333
143.2   143.140267
143.2   143.152213
143.31  143.183771
143.38  143.223017
143.35  143.248413
143.34  143.266731
143.25  143.263384
143.33  143.276708
143.3   143.281366
143.33  143.291093
143.36  143.304874

Unless I am being incredibly dumb (not impossible!), I can only think there has been a change to the mechnanics of how ewm_mean calculates its results.
I have tried changing the ewm_mean parameter values, but I feel I am flailing around, as I simply don't have the knowledge of the mathematical principles behind how it works.
So, ideally, advice on how to adjust ewm_mean for my needs would be perfect.
In order to provide more background, I have rolled my own function, that produces the desired results, but is woefully inneficient as it loops through a Python list:
def add_ema_col(df: pl.DataFrame, column: str, periods: int, smoothing:int = 2) -> pl.DataFrame:
    """Add an *EMA* column to an OHLCV dataframe."""

    values = df.select(column).to_series().to_list()
    ema = [sum(values[:periods]) / periods]

    nones = [None] * (periods - 1)
    
    for price in values[periods:]:
        ema.append((price * (smoothing / (1 + periods))) + ema[-1] * (1 - (smoothing / (1 + periods))))
    
    final_values = pl.Series(nones + ema)

    return (
        df
        .with_columns(
            final_values
        )
    )

df = (
    pl.DataFrame({'Close': values})
    .pipe(lambda df: add_ema_col(df, 'Close', 9))
)

Producing the desired:
Close   
f64 f64
143.15  null
143.1   null
143.06  null
143.01  null
143.03  null
143.09  null
143.14  null
143.18  null
143.2   143.106667
143.2   143.125333
143.2   143.140267
143.31  143.174213
143.38  143.215371
143.35  143.242297
143.34  143.261837
143.25  143.25947
143.33  143.273576
143.3   143.278861
143.33  143.289089
143.36  143.303271

So, ideally I would like to achieve the desired results with ewm_mean, but if that is for some reason not practical, I would welcome feedback on how to convert the principles of my custom function into a Polars expression operating solely on the dataframe without the  need for Python loop & list.
In reality, I would actually welcome answers to both, as I am trying to improve my Polars skills as much as possible, but I don't want to be greedy with other peoples' time!
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
Edit
ewm_mean worked as expected in Polars version: 0.19.14. I am currently using version: 0.20.21.
I have raised this as a defect: ewm_mean produces different results in 0.20.21 than 0.19.14 #15807
If it is a bug, I guess help on making my custom function more efficient would be the most beneficial to me right now.
Btw, I appreciate that I could convert the dataframe to a pyarrow-backed Pandas dataframe and run the TA-Lib function on it, but that is my least favored option right now.

Do you know what version it changed? It seems 0.20.2 (or .3) was the last working version? This should probably be reported as a bug.

I've just tried it in 0.19.14 and it works as expected. I guess I'm not sure whether this is a bug or what the developers consider a legitimate fix to something else, but I'll raise it and see what they come back with. I'm not sure how much priority this will get, so I guess I will either need to make my custom function more efficient, or I could temporarily convert the Polars dataframe to a PyArrow-backed Pandas dataframe where I can run TA-Lib. Although, I really don't like that option!

A change to cum_count caused the issue. Details.
Changing the code for a condition of cum_count being <= 9, rather than < 9 resolved my issue:
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col('value').cum_count() <= 9)
    .then(pl.col('value').head(9).mean())
    .otherwise(pl.col('value'))
    .ewm_mean(span=9, min_periods=9, ignore_nulls=True, adjust=False)
    .alias('ema_9')
)

